# Native SSRS user security

Tags: reporting-services

In order to allow users to simply run SSRS reports in native mode, where must I add them as users? Right now, it seems like they need to have access to the report in the SSRS Report Manager and access to the SSRS report server (being added as a user on the server). I have an AD group for those who can run reports, but giving adding all of them as a user on the server seems like overkill, even if none of them ever log in.

Am I missing something, or is this completely normal?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when I deploy reports to a SSRS instance I use a "ReportAdmin" user with a secure password. I set my projects configurations up to deploy to multiple servers. In this setup all ssrs servers have two window user accounts, "ReportAdmin" and "ReportUser". The two user are added to the ssrs instances as roles, one that has admin rights and the other with view rights. Clients for report consumption use the "ReportUser" role.